# IndexOf() buscar palabra en una frase

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente codigo en java. Lo que trato de buscar es la palabra sql dentro de mi variable a pero yo ingreso lenguaje sql y me sale que la palabra no ha sido encontrada. Como puedo hacer para buscar sql aunque ingrese lenguaje sql de la variable a? espero me puedan ayudar gracias

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            String a="sql";
            int intIndex = a.indexOf("lenguaje sql");
          if(intIndex == - 1){
             System.out.println("palabra encontrada");
          }else{
             System.out.println("palabra no encontrada"
             + intIndex);
          }

        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

El método `String#indexOf` tratará de buscar **el texto completo** de lo que indiques dentro de la cadena de texto. Como tu cadena de texto tiene el valor `"sql"` y estás buscando `"lenguaje sql"`, no lo va a encontrar puesto que no hay ningún rastro de `"lenguaje "`.

Lo que intentas hacer es medio forzoso y quizás no deberías hacerlo. Por otro lado, puede que lo que sea que quieras hacer es buscar si alguna de las "palabras" dentro de tu cadena de texto puede estar embebida en la cadena. Para ello, podrías utilizar el siguiente algoritmo:

```
String cadenaDondeBuscar = "sql";
String loQueQuieroBuscar = "lenguaje sql";
String[] palabras = loQueQuieroBuscar.split("\\s+");
for (String palabra : palabras) {
    if (cadenaDondeBuscar.contains(palabra)) {
        System.out.println("Encontrado");
        //aquí tu lógica en caso que se haya encontrado...
    }
}
```

Por el comentario de Mariano, si se quisiera evaluar la cadena removiendo no solo los espacios en blanco sino también cualquier otro caracter que no sea una vocal o consonante, usamos `\\W+` para separar la cadena:

```
String cadenaDondeBuscar = "sql";
String loQueQuieroBuscar = "lenguaje sql";
String[] palabras = loQueQuieroBuscar.split("\\W+");
for (String palabra : palabras) {
    if (cadenaDondeBuscar.contains(palabra)) {
        System.out.println("Encontrado");
        //aquí tu lógica en caso que se haya encontrado...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

El funcionamiento del método [**`indexOf`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) es al revés.

Debes aplicar el método a la cadena en la que deseas buscar pasándole como parámetro el texto a buscar.

```
String a = "sql";
String texto = "lenguaje sql";
int intIndex = texto.indexOf(a);
```

Answer (score 7):

Puedes también usar [**`contains`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String palabra = "sql";
String texto = "lenguaje sql";
boolean resultado = texto.contains(palabra);

if(resultado){
    System.out.println("palabra encontrada");
}else{
    System.out.println("palabra no encontrada");
}
```

Comment: Excelente solución. Cuando es una letra en particular la que buscas es suficiente.

Answer (score 4):

Todas las otras respuestas son la forma más rápida de ver si una cadena es parte de otra. Sin embargo, al buscar **palabras**, quizás se quiere cumplir con las siguientes condiciones:

- Coincidir **ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas**.
  Encontrando `"palabra"` dentro de `"ejemplo de ¿PaLaBrA?"`.
- Coincidir con **toda la palabra**.
  Y que NO se considere `"la"` como parte de `"dos palabras"`,
  pero que sí coincida con `"(la primera)"`.

Para eso, usaremos una [expresión regular](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), con límites de palabra completa (`\b`) alrededor de la palabra buscada. Es decir que no esté precedida ni sucedida por letras, números o un guión bajo.

**Ejemplo**

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
```

```java
String aguja = "sql";             //palabra buscada
String pajar = "lenguaje SQL";    //texto

//escapar y agregar limites de palabra completa - case-insensitive
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(aguja) + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher match = regex.matcher(pajar);

//la palabra está en el texto??
if (match.find()) {  //si se quiere encontrar todas las ocurrencias: cambiar el if por while
    System.out.println("Encontrado: '" + match.group() 
                     + "' dentro de '" + pajar 
                     + "' en la posición " + match.start());
} else {
    System.out.println("'" + aguja + "' NO está dentro de '" + pajar);
}
```

**Resultado**

```
Encontrado: 'SQL' dentro de 'lenguaje SQL' en la posición 9
```

[<kbd>demo en ideone.com</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Li8MaY)

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera vas a poder contar cuantas veces aparece la segunda cadena dentro de la primera:

```
    String cadena1 = in.nextLine();
    cadena1 = cadena1.toLowerCase();
    String cadena2 = in.nextLine();
    cadena2 = cadena2.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(" ");

    int contador = 0;

    while (cadena1.indexOf(cadena2) > -1) {
        cadena1 = cadena1.substring(cadena1.indexOf(cadena2) + cadena2.length(), cadena1.length());
        contador++;
    }

    System.out.println("La segunda cadena se incluye " + contador + " veces en la primera cadena.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es algo como lo siguiente.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            String a="lenguaje sql";
            int intIndex = a.indexOf("sql");
          if(intIndex == - 1){
             System.out.println("palabra no encontrada");
          }else{
             System.out.println("palabra encontrada a partir del carácter en la posicion: "
             + intIndex);
          }

        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido, gracias por contribuir, pero debes mejorar tu respuesta, revisa [answer]. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Si se quisiera evaluar la cadena removiendo no solo los espacios en blanco sino también cualquier otro caracter que no sea una vocal o consonante, usamos \W+ para separar la cadena:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // TODO code application logic here
    String cadenaDondeBuscar = "sql";
    String loQueQuieroBuscar = sc.nextLine();
    String[] palabras = loQueQuieroBuscar.split("\\W+"); 

    for (String palabra : palabras) {
        if (cadenaDondeBuscar.contentEquals(palabra)) {
            System.out.println("Encontrado");
            //aquí tu lógica en caso que se haya encontrado...
        }
    }
}
```

Con la función **contentEquals** se evalúa que esté la palabra por completo, mientras que en un **contains** valida que al menos un caracter de los pedidos a buscar esté en el String. Saludos.